# Using different projections in insets with Matplotlib/Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, utm, matplotlib

In Matplotlib I can create inset plots with `.inset_axes()`. This works very well with GeoPandas, allowing me to do e.g.:

```
inset = ax.inset_axes([x, y, w, h])
df_main.plot(ax=ax, ...)
df_subset.plot(ax=axin, ...)
ax.indicate_inset_zoom(inset)
```

[image: Using the same projektion]

*However, if I use a different projection for the inset (in this case I would like to use a locale UTM variant), the `.indicate_inset_zoom()` method will not be able to connect the maps.

```
inset = ax.inset_axes([x, y, w, h])
df_main.plot(ax=ax, ...)
df_subset.to_crs("EPSG:3015").plot(ax=axin, ...)
ax.indicate_inset_zoom(inset)
```

[image: Using diffrerent projections]

Is there a way I can tell Matplotlib to do the necessary transformations for me for that to work? Or some other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a proper solution, but I used a workaround to define a separate projection for the `inset_axes` function from [mpl_toolkits](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes), which currently works for me.

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
axin = inset_axes(ax, width=w, height=w, loc="bottom right", 
                 axes_class=cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes, 
                 axes_kwargs=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
df_subset.plot(ax=axin...)
```

This replaces the `inset = ax.inset_axes([x, y, w, h])`. Projection should take most `cartopy.crs` projection names as an argument.